# ¿como puedo hacer para acomodar los segundos y los minutos?

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo algunos ejercicios de javascript y me encontre con la siguiente consigna:

Por cada clase del programa existente, vamos a pedir:
horas, minutos y segundos de cada video. Ej. Si un video dura
2 horas, 38 minutos y 20 segundos, vamos a rellenar 3 campos de texto con
cada dato.
al apretar el botón "Calcular tiempo total", debe mostrar en un
 pre-creado el tiempo total de los videos.

Mi codigo de HTML es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TAREA HORAS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TAREA CALCULAS HORAS R/ARGENTINA PROGRAMA</h1>

    <form>
        <label>CLASE 1</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Indique las horas." id="horas-clase1">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Indique los minutos." id="minutos-clase1">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Indique los segundos." id="segundos-clase1">
    </form>
    <br>
    <form>
        <label>CLASE 2</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Indique las horas." id="horas-clase2">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Indique los minutos." id="minutos-clase2">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Indique los segundos." id="segundos-clase2">
    </form>
    <br>
    <form>
        <label>CLASE 3</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Indique las horas." id="horas-clase3">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Indique los minutos." id="minutos-clase3">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Indique los segundos." id="segundos-clase3">
    </form>
    <br>
    <form>
        <label>CLASE 4</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Indique las horas." id="horas-clase4">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Indique los minutos." id="minutos-clase4">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Indique los segundos." id="segundos-clase4">
    </form>
    <br>
    <form>
        <label>CLASE 5</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Indique las horas." id="horas-clase5">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Indique los minutos." id="minutos-clase5">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Indique los segundos." id="segundos-clase5">
    </form>
    <br>
    <button id="boton-calcular">CALCULAR!</button>
    <br>


    <div id="vacio">
        <strong>

        </strong>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="tareahoras.js"></script>
</html>
```

Mi codigo de JS es el siguiente:

```
const horasTotales = [];
const minutosTotales = [];
const segundosTotales = [];

const botonCalcular = document.querySelector("#boton-calcular")

botonCalcular.onclick = function () {
//HORAS
const horasClase1 = Number(document.querySelector("#horas-clase1").value);
horasTotales.push(horasClase1);

const horasClase2 = Number(document.querySelector("#horas-clase2").value);
horasTotales.push(horasClase2);

const horasClase3 = Number(document.querySelector("#horas-clase3").value);
horasTotales.push(horasClase3);

const horasClase4 = Number(document.querySelector("#horas-clase4").value);
horasTotales.push(horasClase4);


const horasClase5 = Number(document.querySelector("#horas-clase5").value);
horasTotales.push(horasClase5);


let totalHoras = horasTotales.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);  //TOTAL HORAS
                           

//MINUTOS
const minutosClase1 = Number(document.querySelector("#minutos-clase1").value);
minutosTotales.push(minutosClase1);


const minutosClase2 = Number(document.querySelector("#minutos-clase2").value);
minutosTotales.push(minutosClase2);


const minutosClase3 = Number(document.querySelector("#minutos-clase3").value);
minutosTotales.push(minutosClase3);


const minutosClase4 = Number(document.querySelector("#minutos-clase4").value);
minutosTotales.push(minutosClase4);


const minutosClase5 = Number(document.querySelector("#minutos-clase5").value);
minutosTotales.push(minutosClase5);

let totalMinutos = minutosTotales.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);  //TOTAL MINUTOS


//SEGUNDOS
const segundosClase1 = Number(document.querySelector("#segundos-clase1").value);
segundosTotales.push(segundosClase1);


const segundosClase2 = Number(document.querySelector("#segundos-clase2").value);
segundosTotales.push(segundosClase2);


const segundosClase3 = Number(document.querySelector("#segundos-clase3").value);
segundosTotales.push(segundosClase3);


const segundosClase4 = Number(document.querySelector("#segundos-clase4").value);
segundosTotales.push(segundosClase4);



const segundosClase5 = Number(document.querySelector("#segundos-clase5").value);
segundosTotales.push(segundosClase5);

let totalSegundos = segundosTotales.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);  //TOTAL SEGUNDOS


const minutosFinales = totalMinutos % 60;
console.log(minutosFinales)
const segundosFinales = totalSegundos % 60;
console.log(segundosFinales)


document.querySelector("#vacio").innerText = `El total de sus videos es de ${totalHoras} horas, ${totalMinutos} minutos y ${totalSegundos} segundos.`
```

}

Se me hace imposible sumar bien los segundos y minutos y no puedo encontrar la forma, me serviria muchisimo una explicacion.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se ve que casi lo tenias.

Tienes que dividir por 60 para determinar cuántos segundos son en realidad minutos (y quedarte con la parte entera) . Y también ocupar el operador resto entero '%' para determinar con cuantos segundos te quedas.

Por ejemplo, tienes 222 segundos:

- minutos = 222 / 60 = 3.7 => parte entera => 3
- segundos = 222 % 60 = 42

Comprobamos:
3x60 + 42 = 180 + 42 = 222

Luego esos minutos debes sumarlos a los minutos originales y volver a hacer lo mismo, pasando esta vez a las horas.

Por lo tanto al final de tu código tienes que poner algo así:

```
    const segundosFinales = (totalSegundos % 60);
    const minutosAdicionales = parseInt( totalSegundos / 60);
    const minutosFinales = (minutosAdicionales + totalMinutos) % 60;
    const horasAdicionales = parseInt((minutosAdicionales + totalMinutos) / 60);

    document.querySelector("#vacio").innerText = `El total de sus videos es de ${totalHoras + horasAdicionales} horas, ${minutosFinales} minutos y ${segundosFinales} segundos.`;
```

Dos recomendaciones adicionales:

1. Las constates globales que tienes debes ponerlas dentro de la función onclick:

```
botonCalcular.onclick = function() {
const horasTotales = [];
const minutosTotales = [];
const segundosTotales = [];
//...etc
```

Si las tienes fuera, cada vez que presionas el botón "CALCULAR!" se vuelve a sumar sobre el resultado anterior

2. Cada vez que tienes algo como:

```
    const horasClase1 = Number(document.querySelector("#horas-clase1").value);
    horasTotales.push(horasClase1);

    const horasClase2 = Number(document.querySelector("#horas-clase2").value);
    horasTotales.push(horasClase2);

    //etc...hasta horasTotales99999
```

Eso debería estar dentro de un for, imagina tuvieras mil parámetros, te llevaría una vida

### UPDATE ( Leer con un for)

Lo más simple es colocar unas clases de css a las horas, minutos y segundos:

```
<input class="horas" type="number" placeholder="Indique las horas." id="horas-clase1">
<input class="minutos" type="number" placeholder="Indique los minutos." id="minutos-clase1" >
<input class="segundos" type="number" placeholder="Indique los segundos." id="segundos-clase1" >

//ETC...resto de los inputs
```

```
let horas=0;
let minutos=0;
let segundos=0;
document.querySelectorAll(".horas").forEach(
    (el) => {
        horas += Number(el.value);
    });
```

Luego haces lo mismo para minutos y segundos.

### Update 3 (for a función)

Otra mejora es crear una función

```
function GetSumaValores(clase) {
    let suma = 0;
    document.querySelectorAll(clase).forEach(
    (el) => {
        suma += Number(el.value);
    });
    return suma;
}
```

Y luego la llamas:

```
let horas = GetSumaValores(".horas");
let minutos = GetSumaValores(".minutos");
let segundos = GetSumaValores(".segundos");
```

Comment: Sos un crack, me salvaste y lo entendi poerfecto. Voy a enroscarme para meterlo dentro de un for.

Comment: @PipePouyssegur Actualicé la respuesta, para ayudarte un poco con lo que te comentaba del for

Comment: tremendo... super avanazado y eficiente ese codigo. muchas gracias te mando un saludo.